# Why are there no raptors in IE?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, jquery-events

The other day, SmashingMagazine gave the world a wonderful [gift](http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery-raptorize?timed_launch=true). Unfortunately IE (at least IE7) to my shock and amazement, has a problem with it. Does anyone know why the code below would not fire properly in IE7?

It listens for keypresses and fires a function if it can match the konami code. I'm not super knowledgeable on JS events, so any direction would be appreciated.

```
var kkeys = [], konami = "38,38,40,40,37,39,37,39,66,65";
            $(window).bind("keydown.raptorz", function(e){
                kkeys.push( e.keyCode );
                if ( kkeys.toString().indexOf( konami ) >= 0 ) {
                    init();
                    $(window).unbind('keydown.raptorz');
                }
            }, true);
```

EDIT: Can anyone else test this in IE7 to confirm?

Comment: There are... they're [everywhere](http://xkcd.com/135/), ready to strike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery supports `e.which` for the keyCode just in case `e.keyCode` doesn't work.  So try change `e.keyCode` to `e.which`.

But i think it is the `true` as the third argument in the bind.  Take that away and try again.

Here is my copy in JS fiddle of a IE compliant version: [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/X9qse/5/)

UPDATED: wow, the bind for keydown on `$(window)` wasn't working for IE and `$(document.body)` wasn't working for FF, so I did `$(document)` and it works for both....

The link above now has a version that works for both FF and IE at least.

Comment: no dice. I tried e.which earlier. The "true" is there to stop bind from preventing the default action I believe.

Comment: @Sinetheta it would be false then.  If it isn't `=== false` jquery will assume it is the function bound and that the second parameter is the data to be statically bound to the event object

Comment: I have tested FF 4 and IE 8, both work.  IDK for now about other versions

Comment: false would be terrible, then that function steals your keystrokes. Interestingly enough, setting it to false did nothing for my IE7. It ignore the keycaptures completely, which alludes to deeper problems.

Comment: false is just a shortcut for adding e.preventDefault() and e.stopPropagation() to the bottom o your event.  So I just took the false out since its the same as not having it there.

Comment: that's right, which is why this script has "true" in there. otherwise this "joke" script will prevent default on all keystrokes...
But the $(document) did it. big thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have IE handy, but I'd bet it's keyCode tripping you up - I believe you need to do something like this to get the proper key code in a cross browser fashion:

```
var keyPressed = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.charCode;
```

Comment: no luck. that still works fine in chrome but does nothing for ie